# Making Havdallah with Shabbos Clothes

Tags: shabbat, clothing, havdalah

If one makes havdallah "after" Shabbos (i.e. they make it on Sunday or later) is there any reason to wear Shabbos clothing when making havdallah?

(I have no reason to think one *should* wear, just asking to find out if this is discussed or mentioned anywhere that havdallah should be made specifically while wearing Shabbos clothes.)

Comment: do you have a source for wearing shabbos clothes during havdala on motzei shabbos? Such a source would definitely improve the question

Comment: @aBochur This is one of those questions where if i had a source I wouldn't be asking it...

Comment: But you do have some reason to think that this might be discussed somewhere. What is it?

Comment: In that case why not just focus on motzei shabbos? As of now it seems like you're asking about making it on sunday, as if it's obvious that on motzei shabbos one should wear shabbos clothes.

Comment: @Yehoshua Can you please clarify for all of us here whether youre question is in regard to generally wearing Shabbos clothing for Havdallah or specifically when it is made on Sunday? And do you mean putting the Shabbos clothes back on for Havdallah or leaving them on from Shabbos  unti Sunday?

Answer (score -3):

The Magen Avraham 262:2 brings from the Sefer Haguddah siman 143  that one should keep their shabbas clothes on until havdalah has been said.

Text of MA:

ובאגודה סימן קמ"ג כתב שילך בבגדי שבת עד מ"ש אחר הבדלה

The Kaf HaChaim 262:28 says that its correct to leave them until after the melava malka meal.

[image]

Comment: I think you missed a main part of OP's question - "i.e. they make it on Sunday or later)" by "Sunday", I think he means during the day, though we know that M. Shabbat is "Sunday". (If one assumes Havdalah means the one in Amidah, you really don't need any explanation, as it is still Shabbat, and one may not wear weekday clothes until after Shabbat is over.)

Comment: Did you even look at his parentheses?! And Inalso brought the Kaf Hachaim who held until after the melava malka which can only be done after havdalah al hakos

Comment: @DanF But look at the op's response to aBochur in the comments on the question. I'm not really sure what he is asking, and this answer might suit his query quite well.

Comment: @user6591 He Is clearly asking whether one must wear Shabbos clothes during havdalah if the Havdallah is made on Sunday. The question was NOT whether one should leave his clothes on after Shabbos for Havdallah or not.  So Sam's quote is NOT the answer to the question.

Comment: @RibbisRab Again I point to the discussion in the comments and repeat that it is not clear. He indicates that if a proof can be offered that Havdala must be said in shabbos clothing, and that is why people wear them motzai shabbos, not just by default of still having them on, that would answer his question. The problem with this answer is not that it regards motzai shabbos, the problem is that it doesn't take the default of still having them on from shabbos out of the equation.